# Is there a word for an event that happens in most years?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an annually recurring event which doesn't actually occur in every year?  For instance, a family takes an annual vacation almost every year, but some years it doesn't work out: "We missed our _____ vacation this year."

Comment: If you can't set a pattern, then you'll have to go with something more vague like "mostly-annual"

Comment: In your example, "we missed our usual vacation this year."

Comment: *Annual* would be fine in your example. Perfectly understandable.

Comment: If you take a vacation every year but miss a year, you've missed your *annual* vacation.

Comment: I agree with Richard and Silenus, but since that word didn't quite do it for *you*, I'll suggest *quasi-annual*.

Answer (score 1):

"Perennial" should do the trick. Though a literal reading would suggest it means every year, it easily takes on a figurative sense and suits your purposes nicely.

> lasting or existing for a long or apparently infinite time; enduring or continually recurring.